# How to append a character at the end of each word in a file using awk or sed?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Hi I have a file in UNIX with data as below:

cat file.txt

```
obj1,obj2,obj3\
obj3,obj2,obj4,obj1\
obj1\
obj3,obj4
```

I want each words to replaced by _N and I want to be output as below:

```
obj1_N,obj2_N,obj3_N\
obj3_N,obj2_N,obj4_N,obj1_N\
obj1_N\
obj3_N,obj4_N
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO its highly encouraged for users to do add their efforts in form of code which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question.

Comment: Is it correct that your input file sometimes has a space before the backslash at the end of the line and sometimes not? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, don't answer in a comment.

Comment: no there is not space before backslash

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`

```
sed -r 's/[A-Za-z0-9_]+/&_N/g' file
```

In the above command, the word is defined as any sequence of letters, numbers and underscores. You can add or remove any characters into there to customize your own word.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
cat file.txt | sed 's/\(\w\)\(\W\|$\)/\1_N\2/g'
```

The `(\W|$)` means "Match non-word or end-of-string

Comment: or `sed -E 's/(\w+)/\1_N/g' file` -- Don't `cat | ...` that is an Unnecessary Use Of `cat` (UUOc). Instead read or redirect the file.

Comment: Also its a kind request when someone from community has asked OP to add efforts etc in comments then its better to wait for OP to add those efforts in their question, thank you.

Comment: tried the solution cat file.txt | sed 's/\(\w\)\(\W\|$\)/\1_N\2/g' but its only appending to last word only

Answer (score 0):

sed 's/,/_N/g' file.txt | sed 's/$/_N/'

First sed command replaces comma to _N and second sed command replace end of line to _N

Comment: Or just put it into a single command: `sed 's/,/_N,/g;s/$/_N/' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` you can get the output you write.

```
awk '{print gensub(/([0-9])/, "\\1_N", "g", $0)}' file

obj1_N,obj2_N,obj3_N\
obj3_N,obj2_N,obj4_N,obj1_N\
obj1_N\
obj3_N,obj4_N
```

This code:

- `gensub`  function here with `g` for global search and replace.
- regexp with the parentheses `([0-9])` for retrieving the digit with `\\1` in the substitution part.
- the end `_N` you want here at the right of `\\1` without space between `"\\1_N"`
- the focus is in `$0`

The GNU `awk` manual:

> *gensub* provides [...] the ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text. This is done by using parentheses in the regexp to mark the components, and then specifying `\n' in the replacement text, where n is a digit from one to nine.

- The same result if you declare in an initial `-v`  the '_N' and then its name with `\\1`

```
awk -v end="_N" '{print gensub(/([0-9])/, "\\1"end, "g", $0)}' file

obj1_N,obj2_N,obj3_N\
obj3_N,obj2_N,obj4_N,obj1_N\
obj1_N\
obj3_N,obj4_N
```